# Не сохраняются данные в базе

Tags: python, sqlite3, sql

Что я просмотрел? Ошибки не вылетают, но данные в базу не сохраняются. Честно гуглил и много, но решения так и не нашёл.

```
def save_task(self, subject, date):
    print("SAVE")
    self.connection = sqlite.connect('base.db')
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Tasks (Id, Subject, Date) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (self.count_id(), subject, date))
    self.connection.commit()
    self.connection.close()
    # Не забыть про коммит
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно айди вручную проставлять?

Comment: Да. Для странных нужд, если коротко.

Comment: Еще бы структуру бд посмотреть

Comment: Я давно не питонировал, но в этоме коде разве что запрос может упасть (поставлю буддийское ничего на то, что падает из-за дубликата айдишника).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую что-то сделать с запросом.

Comment: @Etki а исключения видно, только если их ловишь?

Comment: Если их не словить, то приложение падает обычно.

Comment: 1. Использовать `sqlite3`, а не `sqlite` модуль.  
2. Использовать параметризированные запросы, вместо строкового форматирования: `.execute("INSERT INTO Tasks (Id, Subject, Date) VALUES(?,?,?)", (self.count_id(), subject, date))`.  
3. Убедиться, что нигде исключение не подавляется неявно, добавить `print('done')` в конце метода.  
4. Можно написать `with self.connection: self.connection.execute(...)`, чтобы commit, rollback автоматически вызывались.  
5. Если не помогает, то создать минимальный самодостаточный пример, который можно было бы попробовать выполнить отдельно и увидеть проблему.

Answer (score 1):

`insert into .... values ...` - или создаст запись, или бросит исключение. Если запись не создана, то 100% было исключение, которое было где то перехвачено в `except`.

И ещё одна очень частая причина такого поведения, пишут в одну БД, а проверяют запись в другой.